# Extract a pattern from a text with Regextract

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a text like this : `(fr_CA_conf_3001_3001_00863211-2_channel1__174c431c-96d2-5a53-b9e4-e04fcc191e61)`

I need to extract the part of text before "__".
the expected result is : `fr_CA_conf_3001_3001_00863211-2_channel1`

Could you please help me to find the right formula using REGEXEXTRACT?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=regexextract(A1,"^\((.*)__")
```

Where cell A1 contains your data.

You can also use an array to work down a sheet of values, like this in say Col B, row 1:

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"",regexextract(A1:A,"^\((.*)__"),))
```